# What is the expected profit?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, transition-matrix

I have been working on the following problem:

The transition matrix of a driver moving in zone 1 to zone 2 and between the zones is given by P= [0.8 0.2, 0.3 0.7]. The state space is {zone1, zone2} The driver’s expected profit for a trip entirely in zone one is 8 dollars, entirely in zone two is 10 dollars and 12 dollars between zones. What is the expected profit per trip?

I have calculated the stationary probability vector as π=(3/5 , 2/5) but i do not know how to relate this to the expected profit. Also i calculated P^20, which converges to [0.6 0.4 , 0.6 0.4].

I tried multiplying the long-term transition probability matrix above by the profits and adding them together but i got 20.8, which does not seem like a likely answer.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! Hope this is better!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm in state 1, the next trip will have average profit 8.8 (0.8 x 8 + 0.2 x 12).  If I'm in state 2, the next trip will have average profit 11.2.  The steady state values indicate that you are in state 1 about 60% of the time and in state 2 the other 40%, so I get 9.76 as the average profit.

Comment: following your thought, wouldn’t being in state 2 give 0.7 x £10 + 0.3 x £12 = £10.6 and therefore an average profit of £9.52?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I'm not sure how I got 11.2 now.......